# Как в меню joomla создать пункт-ссылку на якорь в пределах одной страницы?

Tags: joomla, настройка

Joomla 3.7.4

Есть ряд страниц, на которых необходимо создать свою навигацию посредством модулей меню.
Модуль опубликован, якоря по разделам страницы "раскиданы", как правильно настроить пункты меню?
Благодарю!

Comment: Ничего не понятно, что вы понимаете под "правильно настроить пункты меню"  ?

Comment: Корректное указание ссылки.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OcGor3u9C_w

Comment: Arsen, благодарю, конечно, но Вы видимо неверно поняли вопрос, либо я всё-таки не совсем корректно его сформулировал.  Создавать меню, пункты, публиковать модуль я могу. Мне непонятно как создать пункт меню, который ссылается на якорь на странице.

Comment: Если честно, да трудно было понять, после последнего стало ясно что нужно ), добавлю в ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы создать меню, которое ссылается на якорь в странице, вам необходимо создать новое меню, для `Menu Item Type` - выбрать `External URL` далее в поле `Link` вставляете алиас ссылки, которая ссылается на конкретную страницу( где находятся якоря) и добавляете к нему якорь, например:
`about#anchor1` или `about#anchor2` и т.д